# UICollectionView header affects to prefetch items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

When using **UICollectionViewFlowLayout's** `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true` in UICollectionView, **UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching's** func `prefetchItemsAt indexPaths` always repeats indexPaths, like:

```
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
```

When delete `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true` (or set the value to `false`) array of indexPaths becomes correct in `prefetchItemsAt indexPaths`:

```
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 8], [0, 9]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 10], [0, 11]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 12], [0, 13]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 14], [0, 15]]
collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:) [[0, 16], [0, 17]]
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this?